# Using AJAX script with JMeter

Tags: ajax, webdriver, jmeter

I am currently working to create test samples for an in-house Java web site using Jmeter for performance testing.

After creating / recording some scripts and re-running them, I found that some scripts are failing (not HTTP failures, the response code was 200 so it was a successful HTTP Response, but looks like server side failures) with an error "Unexpected error occurred, Page is closed". I could not figure out exact reason even after enabling high traces for this application.

I found that this web site is using lot of AJAX Requests for every sample I have collected (or most of them) and they are all recorded with samples ending with ".js". After doing a lot of google search about this issue with Jmeter, I found that Jmeter does not run Javascripts as this is not a browser.

Fair enough, went through some more details and read many solutions that  talk about using Selenium web driver to run java scripts and can be used with jmeter to tackle this issue. But none of them talks about exact implementation of webdriver for running javascripts (or Ajax scripts) and having Jmeter running HTTPS Samples.

My Question is two fold:

1) How else I could debug my Jmeter scripts to confirm these errors are caused by Ajax scripts and nothing else and if not Ajax issues, what else is causing this "page closed error"

2) and how do I run web driver for Java scripts and JMeter running http samples in the same test scripts?

Any help or pointers towards a related document is really appreciated. Currently I am completely stuck and don't have any solutions that I could find reading through manuals.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have 2 choices:

1. Use [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) to perform real browser testing (this might be very resource intensive as real browsers consume a lot of CPU and RAM)
2. Use JMeter to execute AJAX calls. JMeter cannot execute JavaScript, but JavaScript-driven HTTP requests can be recorded using i.e. [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and replayed as JMeter HTTP Request samplers. You will need to apply some custom configuration in order to execute AJAX requests in parallel, check out [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article for details.

Comment: I have read the article ( How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter) already and it didn't help me. I have a lot of samples (based on number of steps and each sample recorded with multiple scripts (.js , Ajax). So, recreating one thread separately for each Ajax script, to run in parallel , is not possible with my scenario. This example showed only 3 scripts with 2 Ajax scripts in parallel. Real scenarios are little complex than that and this workaround is not practical(if I understood this article correctly).

Comment: Also, some AJAX Scripts were running fine. it's just few main scripts (where I click on SAVE button or specific action) are failing with this message. So, wondering if there is a way to debug those atleast..